# If I like to take simple script like java script to be wrapper to low level like c++ what I need to do?

Tags: javascript, c++, wrapper

If you know tomcats jasper its jsp wrapper to java class, say I like to do something like this not web related just the general idea to JavaScript and c++, what I need to do?   I mean
What technologies and book and article should I read?   Where to start what concept to follow?

Answer (score 2):

I just recently found out about [Node.js](http://nodejs.org) which might be what you are looking for. It allows JavaScript to be used outside browser and has capability to include C/C++ addons. More about in the [API docs](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.5/api/addons.html).

**EDIT:**
If you want to use JavaScript as a build tool, then [Jake](https://github.com/280north/jake) should do it. It is direct port of [Rake](http://rake.rubyforge.org/) to JavaScript.

Comment: can you control or create new c++ class? does it compile javascript to c++ code ?

Comment: I havent yet used it myself, but what I have gathered, you can reuse what ever C/C++ stuff you have or create new classes. You only need to write a wrapper C++ class, that exports needed functionality to the JavaScript side. This is the same in many languages that support binary extensions written in C/C++.

Comment: i want something like java jasper , to compile the code to native exe
after converting in to generic c++ code

Comment: I think I misunderstood you - you want to compile JS to native, not access C++ classes from JS? If so, then [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118138/is-there-a-native-machine-code-compiler-for-javascript) are some ideas, but as that page also says - JS is very dynamic and you could miss out a lot of features, when trying to compile to static.

Comment: Thanks to the replay but this is NOT what i meant , i like to take JS as the logic script parse the end result to pure c++ code and compile it

Comment: I updated my answer with a reference to Jake. Take a look at that.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try [Lua](http://www.lua.org). There are plenty of tutorials available, i.e. http://heavycoder.com/tutorials/lua_embed.php