# Standalone Node.js application

Tags: node.js

I am considering developing a desktop application composed of 2 parts:

- user interface (Java app for example)
- back-end Node.js server

The 2 parts connect through sockets. Don't ask why I know it's weird.

I will want to be able to provide to customers the application with an installer. I don't want that users have to install Node.js themselves.

Is there a way to have a Node.js server installed as standalone, i.e. no need to install Node.js globally on the system.

**This is a question for any (Windows, Linux, Mac OS X...) environment.**

Comment: A relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794140/is-it-possible-to-create-desktop-applications-with-node-js

Comment: This appears to be part of a Duplicate Pool: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145561/is-there-a-way-to-compile-node-js-source-files, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557364/packing-node-js-scripts-node-exe-into-a-single-executable, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173232/make-exe-from-node-js-app, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794140/is-it-possible-to-create-desktop-applications-with-node-js, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724817/how-to-create-a-stand-alone-command-line-application-with-node-js, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388108/standalone-node-js-application

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I deploy Node.js applications as a single executable file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14314038/how-do-i-deploy-node-js-applications-as-a-single-executable-file)

Comment: @ArtjomB. The question you linked to is 1 year older than mine. And [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557364/packing-node-js-scripts-node-exe-into-a-single-executable) is specifically for Windows, which isn't answering my question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can bundle the binaries with your application. Won't have to install anything to run a Node app. The binaries are [available](http://nodejs.org/download/) on the same page as the installers.

You'll just have to know where the binaries are, but I assume you've got an installer that can put them somewhere known.

```
// To start the node process
$ /path/to/binaries/npm install
$ /path/to/binaries/node myApp.js
```

Comment: Is such packaging legal according to nodejs license?

Comment: it doesn't answer the question

Comment: This answer is outdated/incomplete, there is now a bunch of tools to handle this (see [@CoolAJ86's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18703421/1439688)). Just tried [`pkg`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg) on macOS, it generates one standalone executable file per platform, I tested the `.exe` on an out-of-the-box windows VM, works flawlessly.

Answer (score 39):

**Update 2017-05-04**: And there's a new kid in town:

- [PKG (by zeit)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg)

**Update 2016-11-14**: Nowadays Electron and nwjs seem like the best options.

- [Electron](https://medium.com/developers-writing/building-a-desktop-application-with-electron-204203eeb658#.ua40dkt4c)
- [nwjs-builder](https://github.com/nwjs/nw-builder)

**Original**:

There are a number of steps you have to go through to create an installer and it varies for each Operating System. For Example:

- on Mac OS X you need to create a `.pkg`, there are instructions on how to do that here: https://coolaj86.com/articles/how-to-create-an-osx-pkg-installer.html
- on Ubuntu Linux you need to create a `.deb`, there are instruction on how to do that here: https://coolaj86.com/articles/how-to-create-a-debian-installer.html
- on Microsoft Windows you need to create a `.exe` or `.msi`, there are instruction on how do that using the innosetup installer here: https://coolaj86.com/articles/how-to-create-an-innosetup-installer.html

Answer (score 9):

[Node-Webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) is an option, but it really isn't set-up to do a "server - client" type relationship.

Another option is packaging the node.js installers with you application installer.  Then when the application boot you can spin up a node.js process.  I know some developers have been doing this with titanium, here is a little bit more information [information](http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2011/06/titanium-desktop-node-js-prototype.html).

Hope this helps!

Comment: You can launch a server from node-webkit just in the way you launch it in Node.js. It's just that node-webkit provide another way beyond B/S architecture.

Comment: This doesn't directly answer my question (so I've accepted another one) but this is awesome this is an even better solution that what I was planning to do!! Thank you!!

Comment: @RogerWang Could you explain how to launch a server from node-webkit

Answer (score 4):

Here's an option: [Light Table](http://www.lighttable.com/) is a node app, but installs nicely and integrates the GUI (webkit) cleanly on most OSs.

To do this it leverages [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit). (Runs node code straight from an html page.) Here is the [packaging documentation](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/How-to-package-and-distribute-your-apps).

Answer (score 3):

Worth mentioning [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) made by GitHub. Used for building Atom, Slack, Visual Studio Code and more.

Comment: @jezrael - this is no worse than the rest of the answers. It's the nature of the question.

Answer (score 2):

As of node.js 18.16.0 you can now generate [single executable applications](https://nodejs.org/api/single-executable-applications.html)

Users can create a single executable application from their bundled script with the node binary itself and any tool which can inject resources into the binary.

Here are the steps for creating a single executable application using one such tool, [postject](https://github.com/nodejs/postject):

1. Create a JavaScript file:

```bash
echo 'console.log(`Hello, ${process.argv[2]}!`);' > hello.js
```

2. Create a configuration file building a blob that can be injected into the single executable application (see [Generating single executable preparation blobs](https://nodejs.org/api/single-executable-applications.html#generating-single-executable-preparation-blobs) for details):

```bash
echo '{ "main": "hello.js", "output": "sea-prep.blob" }' > sea-config.json
```

3. Generate the blob to be injected:

```bash
node --experimental-sea-config sea-config.json
```

4. Create a copy of the node executable and name it according to your needs:

- On systems other than Windows:

  ```bash
  cp $(command -v node) hello
  ```
- On Windows:

  Using PowerShell:

  ```bash
  cp (Get-Command node).Source hello.exe
  ```

  Using Command Prompt:

  ```bash
  for /F "tokens=*" %n IN ('where.exe node') DO @(copy "%n" hello.exe)
  ```

  The .exe extension is necessary.

5. Remove the signature of the binary (macOS and Windows only):

- On macOS:

```bash
codesign --remove-signature hello
```

- On Windows (optional):

[signtool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/signtool) can be used from the installed [Windows SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/). If this step is skipped, ignore any signature-related warning from postject.

```bash
signtool remove /s hello.exe
```

6. Inject the blob into the copied binary by running postject with the following options:

- `hello` / `hello.exe` - The name of the copy of the node executable created in step 4.
- `NODE_SEA_BLOB` - The name of the resource / note / section in the binary where the contents of the blob will be stored.
- `sea-prep.blob` - The name of the blob created in step 1.
- `--sentinel-fuse NODE_SEA_FUSE_fce680ab2cc467b6e072b8b5df1996b2` - The fuse used by the Node.js project to detect if a file has been injected.
- `--macho-segment-name NODE_SEA` (only needed on macOS) - The name of the segment in the binary where the contents of the blob will be stored.

To summarize, here is the required command for each platform:

- On Linux:

```bash
npx postject hello NODE_SEA_BLOB sea-prep.blob \
    --sentinel-fuse NODE_SEA_FUSE_fce680ab2cc467b6e072b8b5df1996b2
```

- On Windows - PowerShell:

```bash
npx postject hello.exe NODE_SEA_BLOB sea-prep.blob `
    --sentinel-fuse NODE_SEA_FUSE_fce680ab2cc467b6e072b8b5df1996b2
```

- On Windows - Command Prompt:

```bash
npx postject hello.exe NODE_SEA_BLOB sea-prep.blob ^
    --sentinel-fuse NODE_SEA_FUSE_fce680ab2cc467b6e072b8b5df1996b2
```

- On macOS:

```bash
npx postject hello NODE_SEA_BLOB sea-prep.blob \
    --sentinel-fuse NODE_SEA_FUSE_fce680ab2cc467b6e072b8b5df1996b2 \
    --macho-segment-name NODE_SEA
```

7. Sign the binary (macOS and Windows only):

- On macOS:

```bash
codesign --sign - hello
```

- On Windows (optional):

A certificate needs to be present for this to work. However, the unsigned binary would still be runnable.

```bash
signtool sign /fd SHA256 hello.exe
```

8. Run the binary:

- On systems other than Windows

```bash
$ ./hello world
Hello, world!
```

- On Windows

```bash
$ .\hello.exe world
Hello, world!
```

Answer (score 1):

I’ve just stumbled upon [nexe](https://github.com/crcn/nexe) – a tool which “creates a single executable out of your node.js app”.

I haven’t tried it out yet, but I guess that even works without an installer – producing just a single standalone binary.

Comment: Just tried using it. Had a lot of problems. It would fail silently a lot. I never got it working in some of my use cases so I switched to pkg mentioned above and had to problems.