# Node JS wrapper to mac os (.pkg, .app)

Tags: javascript, node.js, xcode, macos, wrapper

I want to wrap my nodejs app for mac osx -> .pkg or .app file.

Whats the best way to do it? 
Tutorial / tools will be appreciated.

Thanks
Asaf

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14314038/how-do-i-deploy-node-js-applications-as-a-single-executable-file/18703407#18703407

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this 
https://electron.atom.io/ 
Great tool too wrap NodeJS projects for mac and window executables.

Answer (score 0):

Use node [pkg](https://github.com/zeit/pkg) module. You'll be able to create executables for mac, windows and linux.