# Can the "MEAN" Stack run native?

Tags: node.js, installation, mean-stack

I'm wondering if one were to create a folder containing NodeJS and MongoDB binaries for Windows, Mac or Linux and built a project to reference the corresponding download executable etc. *Now I have been seeing this done using node as part of a native software, but* **can one conceivably create a basic installer for each OS to turn it all on and run a somewhat native "mean" program?** Is this already a thing and I'm like a month (*a light year in dev*) behind?

And I mean purely the technology and the capability, before someone makes a rant about licencing.

Comment: Sure, you could conceivably bundle everything into a single installer (MEAN stack plus your app). For example: [Bitnami](https://bitnami.com/stack/mean/installer). Recommending how to do so is outside the scope of a [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) programming question.

Comment: Thanks @Stennie, Ya I'm wondering if there are things like Bitnami, with the whole browser wrapper like ionic, phonegap, cordova etc. Can't expect a full project as an answer obviously.

Comment: There are many solutions for packaging up node apps (including a browser): [Is it possible to create desktop applications with node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794140), [Standalone Node.js application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388108/), and so forth. So the answer to your "is it possible" question is "Yes, you can conceivably create an installer". Solutions like node-webkit have been around for a few years (early 2012) so indeed you probably are late to the party ;-).

Comment: Good to know! I guess I am new to the idea, but to my credit searching around for it isn't especially revealing either.