# Package a Node.js application as an OS X application

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, native, packaging

I want to build an interface for a series of terminal commands that our developers use to manage their development environments. I'd like to try to build it in Node.js.

Now, I'm thinking I can create it as an HTML5/CSS 3/JavaScript application using [Express.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express.js), etc... and then would like to package it as a native OS X application. Meaning, an application that I can just send them, they double click on and run, but that either launches a Chrome browser and navigates to the localhost:port server that hits the script or simply starts the server and instructs the user to go to the URL. Either way is fine.

I am doing this because I need access to the local system to be able to configure a number of things and interact with any number of running (headless VMs). So I can't simply serve this from a server and have them visit the site.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this actually have to be a .app package? If not, it might be simpler to create a shell script that does all the launching stuff, and just call that MyApp.command, and package it alongside a local build of node and your source inside a zipfile or dmg or whatever. If it does need to be a .app, the simplest solutions will involve just directly launching the JS script, so you'll have to write the js code to launch the browser for the user (not that hard). If it needs to be a .app and you can't modify the JS, then you'll need to create a custom .app wrapper. So, which do you want?

Comment: PS, there is not (yet) a node.js equivalent to py2app, etc., that would make the intermediate solution really easy. From what I understand, http://appjs.org/ is the most promising option at this point, but the current release doesn't work on Mac… so you'll still have to do a good deal of work even if you go with the theoretically "easy" way.

Comment: PPS, also see https://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/browse_thread/thread/f90b3f1c747d20b3 (although that's more about bundling a WebKit GUI into the app, instead of launching the user's default browser).

Comment: Anyone know what the progress on this has been? Looks like appjs has been deprecated.

Answer (score 17):

Option 1: [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) (formerly atom-shell)

This is the shell that GitHub's [Atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(text_editor)) and Microsoft's [Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) editors use. It’s very similar to node-webkit, though it will run the script first, and you have to create a view/window for the user.  There are some other minor differences, but it's worth looking at.

---

Option 2: [NW.js](http://nwjs.io/) formerly node-webkit

The gist is that it basically extends the JavaScript engine for you to write a web-based application supporting [Node.js'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) extended object model, and modules... you then package your *package.json* *start.html* modules and JavaScript files into a ZIP file (with the .nw extension) and run it with nw(.exe) .. there are Windows, Mac and Linux builds available.

---

Option 3: [Neutralinojs](https://neutralino.js.org/) [Github](https://github.com/neutralinojs/neutralinojs)

Neutralinojs is a lightweight and portable desktop application development framework. It lets you develop lightweight cross-platform desktop applications using JavaScript, HTML and CSS. You can extend Neutralinojs with any programming language (via extensions IPC) and use Neutralinojs as a part of any source file (via child processes IPC).

---

Option 4: [MacGapNode](https://github.com/node-app/MacGapNode) (OS X *only*)

MacGap with Node.js integration (it *seems* to be getting stale)

---

Option 5: [Tauri](https://tauri.studio/en/docs/about/intro) [Github](https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri)

Tauri is a toolkit that helps developers make applications for the major desktop platforms - using virtually any frontend framework in existence. The core is built with Rust and the CLI leverages Node.js making Tauri a genuinely polyglot approach to creating and maintaining great apps.

---

Aside: Services...

I can't speak for OS X on this as a .App, but it could well be possible to create a background service install in Node.js and a link to a "local" site on the desktop.  Most browsers have an option to not show all the features (I know Firefox in particular does).

I know your question is to OS X in particular, but in Windows you can use NSSM to run anything as a service, and I have used it for Node.js-based services in Windows.  I think some of the other options above are better depending on your needs though.

---

Removed:

- <strike>[nexe](https://github.com/crcn/nexe)</strike> - stale/unmaintained
- <strike>[AppJS](http://appjs.org/)</strike> - replaced with DeskShell
- <strike>[DeskShell](https://github.com/sihorton/appjs-deskshell)</strike> - stale, website offline
- <strike>[node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit)</strike> - renamed to NW.js
- <strike>[XULRunner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XULRunner)</strike> project stalled, and exceedingly behind.
- <strike>[Thrust](https://github.com/breach/thrust) ([Node Adapter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-thrust))</strike> - deprecated/stale
- <strike>[Carlo](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/carlo) [Chrom(ium)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_(web_browser)) shell from Node.js.</strike> - unmaintained/stale

---

This answer is copied for multiple questions, and these references are mostly for updating convenience.

- *[Packaging a Node.js web application as a normal desktop application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12486874/43906)*
- *[Package a Node.js application as an OS X application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27830697/43906)*

Comment: @JasonJ.Nathan thanks, updated to remove thrust, and add Carlo in.

Comment: Carlo is interesting in that it assumes Chrome is installed. Very interesting indeed :)

Comment: Carlo is now officially unmaintained – might make sense to remove it from the list @Tracker1 (Source: https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/carlo/issues/163#issuecomment-592238093)

Comment: Tauri should be coming up on this list shortly

Comment: @st_phan deprecated carlo

Comment: @rx2347 added tauri

Answer (score 10):

Here's a screencast + writeup on the subject of an installer (.pkg):

[How to create an OS X pkg for NodeJS apps](https://coolaj86.com/articles/how-to-create-an-osx-pkg-installer.html)

As for the .app, I'm not sure yet, but I'm hot on the trail.

Also:

- [How to create a Node.js app .deb for Ubuntu Linux](https://coolaj86.com/articles/how-to-create-a-debian-installer.html)
- [How to create a Node.js app .exe for Microsoft Windows](https://coolaj86.com/articles/how-to-create-an-innosetup-installer.html)

Comment: Can you summarise here? Those links may break at any time.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [AppJS](http://appjs.com/) - "Build Desktop Applications for Linux, Windows and Mac using HTML, CSS and JavaScript"

It sounds like a good match :)

Comment: Per https://twitter.com/appjs/status/394911856910823424 - appjs was superseded by https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit

Comment: Per the reference: *"AppJS project has not been actively developed for a few years. Please check out NW.js or Electron instead."*

Answer (score 3):

Check out [NW.js](http://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) - it's a project sponsored by Intel to package up Node.js applications for the desktop.

Specifically, see *[Creating Desktop Applications With node-webkit](http://strongloop.com/strongblog/creating-desktop-applications-with-node-webkit/)*.

Answer (score 2):

If you compile Node.js from source, every JavaScript file from Node.js' `lib` folder will be included into the binary. That same way could pack your code into the binary.

I am not familiar how Mac OS X packages are created, but at the end it does not seem to be [very hard](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20030619213002144). Just pack your custom Node.js binary into one.