# Compiling nodejs code for safer distribution

Tags: javascript, node.js, compiler-construction

Is there any software that I can use to compile nodejs program?

The reason I want to compile nodejs code is to make it safely distributable.
For example for a desktop application,etc.

And also I want to know whether nodejs will execute faster if compiled as it is asynchronous already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript is not a compiled language and Node.js is Javascript. It will be executed and interpreted at runtime. You can process your javascript with tool like grunt.js for example lint-test and uglify it, but be careful so that do not break the npm system since it is based on certain conventions.

To package your javascript for distribution in the node.js context build an npm module.
https://www.npmjs.org/doc/developers.html

For distributing javascript to the desktop client: Remember it's Javascript an it need to be executed in the Javascript VM. So to have some UI you need to run it in the browser or you need to have some webkit compiled dll to run your code...
something like this...
http://www.tidesdk.org/

You can also use:  http://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit (Thanks to @edi9999)

Comment: I prefer to use https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit rather than tidesdk, tidesdk is not that well maintained

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do that with v8, it has only JIT option. It possible to make a "snapshot" with v8, but it's not exactly the same as compilation and node.js doesn't have support for this feature (also it might produce slower code).  Also all your code will be available with `toString()` of functions.

You might be interested in [JXcore](http://jxcore.com/) project. It is a fork of node and as far as I know has some solution to code protection. Also one of the project goals is to develop javascript-to-LLVM compiler. Of course it can't have full support for ES specification (`eval`, `new Function` etc).

Comment: Don't know details of JXcore but it says it uses encryption. Since it uses V8 internally (its a fork of node), at some point of time it will need the plain js. Won't this be a vulnerability. Compilation cannot be reversed, this is more like packaging. You know like jars.

Comment: @user568109 it uses a modified V8 for that purpose

Comment: JXcore now uses also SpiderMonkey engine (apart from V8). And yes it is more like packaging now. Since it is an open source project already, it does not guarantee code protection by encryption anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to 'compile' a nodejs program, as the javascript is interpreted at run time.

However, if you want to protect your code, you could maybe use something like [Uglify JS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) to make the javascript less readable. However, this won't hinder people to change around your code.

Comment: thanks for ur answer, But I have another question even python is interpreted right but still there are python compilers http://effbot.org/zone/python-compile.htm why is there no way to compile nodejs? , Thanks

Comment: This answer may probably give you a better idea about how the js interpretation works : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145561/is-there-a-way-to-compile-node-js-source-files

Answer (score 0):

The closest you might get to acheiving your goal is to create a self-executing Javascript bytecode wrapper.

A project that does this is [`pkg`](https://github.com/vercel/pkg)

It somehow creates a self-contained binary executable from Javascript, including module dependencies and asset files and produces a self-contained executable.

Installation and use is easy:

```
$ npm install -g pkg
$ pkg index.js -o my-program
$ ./my-program
```

It seems the resulting binary contains nodejs bytecode.  It appears that you can cross-compile.

Answer (score 0):

As of 21+ version, nodejs has built in feature for stand alone running app.

https://nodejs.org/api/single-executable-applications.html