# Is Javascript fully compilable

Tags: javascript, compilation, executable

I am new to javascript and I recently learned that javascript was JIT compiled but if javascript is JIT compilable, can't we just compile a whole program to create an executable ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1118138/438992 etc.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Deno CLI can compile javascript scripts to self-contained executables.

See this https://deno.com/manual@v1.33.2/tools/compiler

Comment: I wonder if there's really any translation to machine code, or if it just embeds a script into t text/data section of an executable and then feeds that into a JavaScript runtime.